# I've got Undefined offset: 9 .Line Number: 42 from $string

Tags: php, html, string, offset

I've been searching for fixing this in a whole day.
When i try to debug, there's message like :

> Blockquote
>   Message: Undefined offset: 9 |
>   Filename: views/view_viewnews.php |
>   Line Number: 42

```
        <?php
            echo '<span id ="title">'.$string[0][4].'</span>';
            $date_str = $string[0][9];
            $date_str=substr($date_str,0,10);
            echo '<span id ="author">'.$string[1][0].' /'.$date_str.'</span>'; 
        ?>
```

Where i could go wrong? Any Help ? Thanks !

Comment: Can you say what will be the value of $date_str?

Comment: `var_dump($string)` and see what is in it.

Comment: Yes there is, i used  $string = json_decode($jsonfile,true);

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_str = $string[0][9];
```

You don't have a value for the 10th value of array $string[0]

That's why.

Comment: Hm. lemme double check from jsonfile. i;ve got the value from there. IF just if, i only have 6 value then $date_str = $string[0][5];  ?

Comment: Right. Array starts at 0. If you are expecting the 9th value, you should 'ask' the 8th.

Comment: @LinaLyn put the answer as resolved by clicking the check thanks.